# Operation time limit

Tags: python, maya

is there a way to time limit the oparations in python, eg:

```
try:
    cmds.file( file, o=1, pmt=0 )
except:
    print "Sorry, run out of time"
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Mac or a Unix-based system, you can use `signal.SIGALRM` to forcibly time out functions that take too long, so your code would look like:

```
import signal

class TimeoutException(Exception):   # custom exception
    pass

def timeout_handler(signum, frame):   # raises exception when signal sent
    raise TimeoutException

# Makes it so that when SIGALRM signal sent, it calls the function timeout_handler, which raises your exception
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)

# Start the timer. Once 5 seconds are over, a SIGALRM signal is sent.
signal.alarm(5)
try:
    cmds.file( file, o=1, pmt=0 )
except TimeoutException:
    print "Sorry, run out of time" # you don't need pass because that's in the exception definition
```

Basically, you're creating a custom exception that's raised when the after the time limit is up (i.e., the `SIGALRM` is sent). You can of course tweak the time limit.

Comment: Unfortunately Im on Windows, but I think I can use it on win too 

https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: If `cmds.file()` is what you want to time, you're out of luck - it blocks on the main thread and even if your timer fires properly on a second thread you won't have a non-crashy way to cancel the operation.   For `cmds.file`, I think your only option may be to launch a maya instance is a subprocess and then kill the subprocess entirely if it times out.